# how to view an html document as a webpage in aws s3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a couple of html files uploaded in aws s3. I am doing that via nodejs. When trying to view the .html file as a webpage, the file keeps on auto downloading and does not allow me to view it in the browser.

How can we view those files in the browser?

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/gettingstarted/latest/swh/website-hosting-intro.html

Comment: i still cant stop them from auto downloading

Answer (score 0):

Uncheck the Download option in S3 Access policy.